# JS validating a dot notation string

Tags: javascript, validation

Let's say I have an existing Items Array:

```
const existingItems = [
    {
      "path": "xxx.yyy.zzz"
    },
    {
      "path": "yyy.xxx.zzz"
    }
  ];
```

Than User will add a new Element to this array - For Example :

```
const newItem = {
    "path": "yyy.xxx"
  };
```

how can I validate that the newItem.path will not match any absolute path?

I have tried few approaches but every time falls on a different if statement which makes it very dirty code. any nice magic function to achieve the following scenarios ?

For example :

Scenario 1 :
 **When new Path is part of Existing Path**

```
let current = 'yyy.xxx.zzz'; // current existing Item
let newPath =  'yyy.xxx'; //new
```

// NOT VALID => Expect false

Scenario 2 :
 **When new path is included in a Part of Existing Path**

```
let current = 'yyy.xxx.zzz'; // current existing Item
let newPath =  'yyy.xxx.z'; //new
```

// VALID => Expect true

Scenario 3 :
 **When new path containing an Existing Path**

```
 let current = 'yyy.xxx.zzz'; // current existing Item
 let newPath =  'yyy.xxx.zzz.ggg '; //new
```

// NOT VALID => Expect false

Scenario 4 :
 **When new path is included in a Part of Existing Path**

```
let current = 'yyy.xxx.zzz'; // current existing Item
let newPath = 'yy'; //new
```

// VALID  => Expect true

Scenario 5 :
 **When new path is included more than once**

```
let current = 'yyy.xxx.zzz'; // current existing Item
let newPath = 'xxx.yyy.xxx.zzz'; //new
```

// VALID  => Expect true

Scenario 6 :
 **When new path has a dot**

```
 let current = 'yyy.xxx.zzz'; // current existing Item
 let newPath = 'yyy.'; //new
```

// NOT VALID  => Expect false

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.split` to get the subpaths, rhen compare them:

```
  const isValid = parts => parts.every(e => e.length);
  const matches = (parts, other) => parts.every((part, i) => part === other[i]);

 const parts = newItem.path.split(".");
 const existing = existingItems.map(item => item.path.split(".");

 const result = isValid(parts) && existing.every(e => !matches(parts, e));
```

Comment: this is great but it does not cover Scenario 3. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some better ways to achieve this but adapting the answer above to support Scenario 3 looks like this : (Welcome any suggestions)

```
    for(let item of existingItems) {
        const oldparts = (item.path).split(".");
        if(parts.length > oldparts.length) {
            let delta = parts.length - oldparts.length;
            for(let i=1;i<=delta;i++) {
                item.path += '.'+parts[oldparts.length+i-1];
            }
        }
    }
```